# Clickhouse: insert modified existing row with filter

Tags: sql, clickhouse

i have such row (Clickhouse)

```
   UserID     |         Status

   439299         send_to_push_provider
```

i need to duplicate (insert) this row to db but with modified Status field. how do i do that in one sql query (+ where UserID = ...) ?

p.s. i cannot use "ALTER TABLE ... UPDATE"

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but I think you might like ReplacingMergeTree which replaces an existing row - but you better read the docs to fully understand how that works: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/replacingmergetree

Comment: `INSERT INTO table SELECT UserID, 'new_status' AS status FROM table WHERE UserID=439299` ?